# Using compiled node dependencies on different environments

Tags: node.js, centos, npm

I have a node project that I run locally and deploy to a CentOS server. I have a few dependencies, one of which relies on a compiled dependency.

Using npm, I can compile the dependency locally using npm install, and it'll work great. This however is not compiled for the deployment server, so it will break if it is uploaded.

I can compile the dependency on a CentOS box, and it'll work on the server, but it'll break in the local environment.

Can anyone think of a workaround so that I can force node to use the global dependencies in the local environment, and a the local ones on the server?

Thanks!

---

Update:

I've figured out a way to do this for now, it's not elegant, but it works:

1. run npm install on my local environment
2. rename the node_modules folder to node_modules_local
3. run npm install on the server
4. prepend a variable to all `require()` paths
5. set a local environment variable to "development"
6. check if we're in development mode, if we are, set the require path variable to `./node_modules_local`.

Answer (score 2):

Check in the source code of the dependencies (compiled dependencies and js-only-dependencies). When you deploy your app run  'npm rebuild' on the server. Seems like this is the officially recommended way to go. See http://www.mikealrogers.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html for details